# pyautogui won't type from list from csv

Tags: python, list, csv, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a script that will access a Website and make a search and click a download file button. The navigation works fine but I can't get it to type from my list of items. It doesn't type anything at all. When I try `print(my_list[i])` it will print 'SKU123'. How do I get it to type in this value correctly?

Here is the full code:

```
import csv
import pyautogui
import webbrowser
i = 0
pyautogui.PAUSE = 2
with open('test_sku_list.csv' , 'rb') as mycsv:
    reader = csv.reader(mycsv)
my_list = list(reader)

webbrowser.open('website.com', new= 1)

for items in my_list:
    pyautogui.moveTo(0,1) # mouse start point
    pyautogui.moveTo(258, 309, duration = 2) # move to search bar
    pyautogui.click(258, 309, duration = 1.1)# click search bar
    pyautogui.typewrite(my_list[i]) # type index of sting in list
    pyautogui.press('enter') # press enter to search
    pyautogui.moveTo(1198,244, duration = 1) # move mouse to a tab in browser
    pyautogui.click(1198,244,duration  = 1) # click wthat tab
    pyautogui.moveTo(1878, 367, duration = 1) # move to a download button
    pyautogui.click(1878, 367) # click download button
    i += 1
```

Comment: Is your script able to type into other windows, like for Notepad? Which browser are you using, and what version of what operating system do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution/error.

The list is being saved as a list of arrays, not strings. Appending the list as strings or `pyautogui.typewrite(my_list[i][i])` should work.